# How to setup Canon iR2520 Network Scanner?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, canon, scanning

I have at my workplace Canon imageRUNNER 2520 Scan/Print machine. I managed to setup printing but scanning I don't know how. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try scanning with XSane.

Comment: Ofcourse I tried, but it's not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this 64-bit](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0044069.asp?model=) & [this 32-bit](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0044074.asp?model=) drivers.

> The MVI Linux Driver CQue 2.0.5 facilitates the creation and configuration of printer queues on Linux workstations or servers, allowing access to all features of Canon devices (iR, CLC, MF, LBP).

Not sure if it will work, but it's worth trying. Also a bit strange, I use (almost) the same printer and don't have problems. Do you connect directly to the printer or through a print Server ?

Comment: Printing is not problem it prints fine, but I'm having problems with scanning. Do not know how to setup it.

Comment: Yes but I guess the scanning drivers are included in the above package (I don't have an pc on hand right now to test).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
**Connect Ir2520/2525/2530 and pc with Lan/Ethernet Cable.

1. Install virtualbox through Terminal.
2. Download and Install windows xp (https://archive.org/details/WinXPProSP3x86) iso image in virtualbox.
3. Install Color network scangear (https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-2520.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-805439&os=windows%20xp%20%2832-bit%29&language=en)
   **If you want to setup printer in xp (https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/imagerunner/imagerunner-2520.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1448259&os=windows%20xp%20%2832-bit%29&language=en)
4. Install Scan2Pdf (https://sourceforge.net/projects/scantopdf)
5. Enjoy! Scan and Printing.

Virtualbox Help:(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWmD8obq4eQ)